# PHP/CSS particular function where a page on top of a page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I've been trying hard to try and to search any tutorial on how to do this but i can't just seem to describe it in google search without putting in too many words that confuses even google to what i am searching.

- www.runescape.com

When you click the sign in / join button on the navigation bar, it doesnt redirect you to a new webpage. Instead it is put on top of the current page.

I am currently reading more about bootstrap modals. It is indeed the same function. But i am not sure if it is the right one or are there specific ones that i should read about.

Its my first time to ever use bootstrap so i am little confused with all the bootstrap plug-ins and all that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. It's javascript and there are plenty of online resources to choose from. Here's one.
http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/howto-code-modal-window-login-form/

Comment: Yea sorry about that php tag.

I am currently looking around this website tho,

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

but theres alot of it.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals
You need to download bootstrap.js or bootstrap.min.js to use the modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is a term called a `modal` window. It's used to sweeten the user interface & experience for users and supply information.

Since you mentioned twitter's bootstrap, take a look here: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php

This should get you going on how to incorporate a basic `modal` window on your site.

Hope this helps.
Edit: For the bootstrap plugin, check: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Do i need to install any plug in? like modal plugin if there is any